# L2TP VPN connection is failed after reseting the BIOS on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: networking, vpn, l2tp

During the L2TP VPN connection, I get the following error Activation of network connection failed. All credentials are valid since I can connect to the VPN using the Windows machine.

The connecting also could be established on the same Ubuntu machine before resetting the BIOS on the laptop several days ago.

Here is the sys.log output during the connection time:

```
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: <info>  [1605551420.5863] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402" name="Scoperty" pid=2790 uid=1000 result="success"
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch gnome-shell[1705]: JS ERROR: TypeError: item is undefined#012setActiveConnections/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1520:17#012setActiveConnections@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1517:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_syncVpnConnections@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1855:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: <info>  [1605551420.5927] vpn-connection[0x5591db51a4d0,f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402,"Scoperty",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 559
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: <info>  [1605551420.5998] vpn-connection[0x5591db51a4d0,f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402,"Scoperty",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: <info>  [1605551420.6058] vpn-connection[0x5591db51a4d0,f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402,"Scoperty",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: == Stack trace for context 0x5633b1120340 ==
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #0 0x5633b14b2668 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1338 (0x7fc878019780 @ 56)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #1 0x7ffd2e6e5d30 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #2 0x5633b14b25d0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1355 (0x7fc878019808 @ 113)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #3 0x7ffd2e6e6910 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #4 0x5633b14b2530 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:2054 (0x7fc87801c890 @ 216)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #5 0x7ffd2e6e74f0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #6 0x7ffd2e6e75b0 b   self-hosted:916 (0x7fc8a82f12b8 @ 367)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #7 0x7ffd2e6e7630 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7fc8a82d2230 @ 386)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #8 0x5633b14b24a8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:227 (0x7fc8780135e8 @ 37)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #9 0x7ffd2e6e8210 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #10 0x5633b14b2430 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:296 (0x7fc878013b38 @ 12)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #11 0x7ffd2e6e8e10 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7fc8a82d2230 @ 386)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #12 0x5633b14b2398 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1401 (0x7fc8780199a0 @ 179)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #13 0x7ffd2e6e99f0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #14 0x5633b14b22f0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1451 (0x7fc878019b38 @ 161)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #15 0x7ffd2e6ea5d0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #16 0x5633b14b2250 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1515 (0x7fc87801a098 @ 94)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #17 0x7ffd2e6eb1b0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #18 0x5633b14b21c0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1855 (0x7fc87801ae68 @ 122)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #19 0x7ffd2e6ebda0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #20 0x7ffd2e6ebe70 b   self-hosted:918 (0x7fc8a82f12b8 @ 394)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch gnome-shell[2790]: Object NM.ActiveConnection (0x7fc8b0011c80), has been already finalized. Impossible to get any property from it.
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: == Stack trace for context 0x5633b1120340 ==
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #0 0x5633b14b2690 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:2048 (0x7fc87801c890 @ 93)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #1 0x7ffd2e6e6790 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #2 0x7ffd2e6e6850 b   self-hosted:916 (0x7fc8a82f12b8 @ 367)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #3 0x7ffd2e6e68d0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7fc8a82d2230 @ 386)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #4 0x5633b14b2608 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:227 (0x7fc8780135e8 @ 37)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #5 0x7ffd2e6e74b0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #6 0x5633b14b2590 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:296 (0x7fc878013b38 @ 12)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #7 0x7ffd2e6e80b0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7fc8a82d2230 @ 386)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #8 0x5633b14b24f8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1401 (0x7fc8780199a0 @ 179)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #9 0x7ffd2e6e8c90 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #10 0x5633b14b2450 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1451 (0x7fc878019b38 @ 161)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #11 0x7ffd2e6e9870 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #12 0x5633b14b23c0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1520 (0x7fc87801a120 @ 77)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #13 0x5633b14b22f0 i   self-hosted:251 (0x7fc8a82c4ab0 @ 223)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #14 0x5633b14b2250 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1517 (0x7fc87801a098 @ 146)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #15 0x7ffd2e6eb1b0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #16 0x5633b14b21c0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1855 (0x7fc87801ae68 @ 122)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #17 0x7ffd2e6ebda0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #18 0x7ffd2e6ebe70 b   self-hosted:918 (0x7fc8a82f12b8 @ 394)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: == Stack trace for context 0x5633b1120340 ==
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #0 0x5633b14b27c8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1338 (0x7fc878019780 @ 56)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #1 0x7ffd2e6e4fd0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch gnome-shell[2790]: Object NM.ActiveConnection (0x7fc8b0011c80), has been already finalized. Impossible to get any property from it.
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #2 0x5633b14b2730 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1355 (0x7fc878019808 @ 113)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #3 0x7ffd2e6e5bb0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #4 0x5633b14b2690 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:2054 (0x7fc87801c890 @ 216)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #5 0x7ffd2e6e6790 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #6 0x7ffd2e6e6850 b   self-hosted:916 (0x7fc8a82f12b8 @ 367)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #7 0x7ffd2e6e68d0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7fc8a82d2230 @ 386)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #8 0x5633b14b2608 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:227 (0x7fc8780135e8 @ 37)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #9 0x7ffd2e6e74b0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #10 0x5633b14b2590 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:296 (0x7fc878013b38 @ 12)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #11 0x7ffd2e6e80b0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7fc8a82d2230 @ 386)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #12 0x5633b14b24f8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1401 (0x7fc8780199a0 @ 179)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #13 0x7ffd2e6e8c90 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #14 0x5633b14b2450 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1451 (0x7fc878019b38 @ 161)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #15 0x7ffd2e6e9870 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #16 0x5633b14b23c0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1520 (0x7fc87801a120 @ 77)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #17 0x5633b14b22f0 i   self-hosted:251 (0x7fc8a82c4ab0 @ 223)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #18 0x5633b14b2250 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1517 (0x7fc87801a098 @ 146)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #19 0x7ffd2e6eb1b0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #20 0x5633b14b21c0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1855 (0x7fc87801ae68 @ 122)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #21 0x7ffd2e6ebda0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #22 0x7ffd2e6ebe70 b   self-hosted:918 (0x7fc8a82f12b8 @ 394)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch gnome-shell[2790]: Object NM.ActiveConnection (0x7fc8b0011c80), has been already finalized. Impossible to get any property from it.
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: == Stack trace for context 0x5633b1120340 ==
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #0 0x5633b14b2250 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:2048 (0x7fc87801c890 @ 93)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #1 0x7ffd2e6eb1b0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #2 0x5633b14b21c0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1857 (0x7fc87801ae68 @ 138)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #3 0x7ffd2e6ebda0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #4 0x7ffd2e6ebe70 b   self-hosted:918 (0x7fc8a82f12b8 @ 394)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: == Stack trace for context 0x5633b1120340 ==
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #0 0x5633b14b2388 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1338 (0x7fc878019780 @ 56)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #1 0x7ffd2e6e99f0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #2 0x5633b14b22f0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1355 (0x7fc878019808 @ 113)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #3 0x7ffd2e6ea5d0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #4 0x5633b14b2250 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:2054 (0x7fc87801c890 @ 216)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #5 0x7ffd2e6eb1b0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #6 0x5633b14b21c0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1857 (0x7fc87801ae68 @ 138)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #7 0x7ffd2e6ebda0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fc8a82b5de0 @ 71)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2790]: #8 0x7ffd2e6ebe70 b   self-hosted:918 (0x7fc8a82f12b8 @ 394)
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch gnome-shell[2790]: Object NM.ActiveConnection (0x7fc8b0011c80), has been already finalized. Impossible to get any property from it.
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch gnome-shell[2790]: Object NM.ActiveConnection (0x7fc8b0011c80), has been already finalized. Impossible to get any property from it.
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch nm-l2tp-service[559]: Check port 1701
Nov 16 20:30:20 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec failed: starter is not running
Nov 16 20:30:22 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: Starting strongSwan 5.6.2 IPsec [starter]...
Nov 16 20:30:22 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: Loading config setup
Nov 16 20:30:22 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: Loading conn 'f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402'
Nov 16 20:30:22 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: found netkey IPsec stack
Nov 16 20:30:22 treshch charon: 00[DMN] Starting IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.6.2, Linux 4.15.0-123-generic, x86_64)
Nov 16 20:30:22 treshch charon: 00[CFG] loading ca certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts'
Nov 16 20:30:22 treshch charon: 00[CFG] loading aa certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/aacerts'
Nov 16 20:30:22 treshch charon: 00[CFG] loading ocsp signer certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/ocspcerts'
Nov 16 20:30:22 treshch charon: 00[CFG] loading attribute certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/acerts'
Nov 16 20:30:22 treshch charon: 00[CFG] loading crls from '/etc/ipsec.d/crls'
Nov 16 20:30:22 treshch charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
Nov 16 20:30:22 treshch charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/ipsec.nm-l2tp.secrets'
Nov 16 20:30:22 treshch charon: 00[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
Nov 16 20:30:22 treshch charon: 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md4 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark stroke updown eap-mschapv2 xauth-generic counters
Nov 16 20:30:22 treshch charon: 00[LIB] dropped capabilities, running as uid 0, gid 0
Nov 16 20:30:22 treshch charon: 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
Nov 16 20:30:22 treshch charon: 04[CFG] received stroke: add connection 'f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402'
Nov 16 20:30:22 treshch charon: 04[CFG] added configuration 'f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402'
Nov 16 20:30:23 treshch charon: 06[CFG] rereading secrets
Nov 16 20:30:23 treshch charon: 06[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
Nov 16 20:30:23 treshch charon: 06[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/ipsec.nm-l2tp.secrets'
Nov 16 20:30:23 treshch charon: 06[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
Nov 16 20:30:23 treshch charon: 08[CFG] received stroke: initiate 'f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402'
Nov 16 20:30:23 treshch charon: 10[IKE] initiating Main Mode IKE_SA f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402[1] to 176.95.171.124
Nov 16 20:30:23 treshch charon: 10[ENC] generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V ]
Nov 16 20:30:23 treshch charon: 10[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.0.101[500] to 176.95.171.124[500] (532 bytes)
Nov 16 20:30:23 treshch charon: 11[NET] received packet: from 176.95.171.124[500] to 192.168.0.101[500] (136 bytes)
Nov 16 20:30:23 treshch charon: 11[ENC] parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ SA V V V ]
Nov 16 20:30:23 treshch charon: 11[IKE] received XAuth vendor ID
Nov 16 20:30:23 treshch charon: 11[IKE] received DPD vendor ID
Nov 16 20:30:23 treshch charon: 11[IKE] received NAT-T (RFC 3947) vendor ID
Nov 16 20:30:23 treshch charon: 11[ENC] generating ID_PROT request 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]
Nov 16 20:30:23 treshch charon: 11[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.0.101[500] to 176.95.171.124[500] (372 bytes)
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 12[NET] received packet: from 176.95.171.124[500] to 192.168.0.101[500] (372 bytes)
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 12[ENC] parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 12[IKE] local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 12[IKE] remote host is behind NAT
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 12[ENC] generating ID_PROT request 0 [ ID HASH ]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 12[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.0.101[4500] to 176.95.171.124[4500] (76 bytes)
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 13[NET] received packet: from 176.95.171.124[4500] to 192.168.0.101[4500] (76 bytes)
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 13[ENC] parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ ID HASH ]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 13[IKE] IKE_SA f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402[1] established between 192.168.0.101[192.168.0.101]...176.95.171.124[192.168.178.21]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 13[IKE] scheduling reauthentication in 9991s
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 13[IKE] maximum IKE_SA lifetime 10531s
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 13[ENC] generating QUICK_MODE request 3253645011 [ HASH SA No ID ID NAT-OA NAT-OA ]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 13[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.0.101[4500] to 176.95.171.124[4500] (252 bytes)
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 14[NET] received packet: from 176.95.171.124[4500] to 192.168.0.101[4500] (204 bytes)
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 14[ENC] parsed QUICK_MODE response 3253645011 [ HASH SA No ID ID NAT-OA NAT-OA ]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 14[IKE] CHILD_SA f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402{1} established with SPIs c236f2de_i c2764521_o and TS 192.168.0.101/32[udp/l2f] === 176.95.171.124/32[udp/l2f]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 14[ENC] generating QUICK_MODE request 3253645011 [ HASH ]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: initiating Main Mode IKE_SA f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402[1] to 176.95.171.124
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V ]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: sending packet: from 192.168.0.101[500] to 176.95.171.124[500] (532 bytes)
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: received packet: from 176.95.171.124[500] to 192.168.0.101[500] (136 bytes)
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ SA V V V ]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: received XAuth vendor ID
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: received DPD vendor ID
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: received NAT-T (RFC 3947) vendor ID
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: sending packet: from 192.168.0.101[500] to 176.95.171.124[500] (372 bytes)
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: received packet: from 176.95.171.124[500] to 192.168.0.101[500] (372 bytes)
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: remote host is behind NAT
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ ID HASH ]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: sending packet: from 192.168.0.101[4500] to 176.95.171.124[4500] (76 bytes)
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: received packet: from 176.95.171.124[4500] to 192.168.0.101[4500] (76 bytes)
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ ID HASH ]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: IKE_SA f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402[1] established between 192.168.0.101[192.168.0.101]...176.95.171.124[192.168.178.21]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: scheduling reauthentication in 9991s
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: maximum IKE_SA lifetime 10531s
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: generating QUICK_MODE request 3253645011 [ HASH SA No ID ID NAT-OA NAT-OA ]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: sending packet: from 192.168.0.101[4500] to 176.95.171.124[4500] (252 bytes)
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: received packet: from 176.95.171.124[4500] to 192.168.0.101[4500] (204 bytes)
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: parsed QUICK_MODE response 3253645011 [ HASH SA No ID ID NAT-OA NAT-OA ]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: CHILD_SA f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402{1} established with SPIs c236f2de_i c2764521_o and TS 192.168.0.101/32[udp/l2f] === 176.95.171.124/32[udp/l2f]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: connection 'f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402' established successfully
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 14[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.0.101[4500] to 176.95.171.124[4500] (60 bytes)
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 01[NET] received packet: from 176.95.171.124[4500] to 192.168.0.101[4500] (76 bytes)
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 01[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 2416597718 [ HASH D ]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 01[IKE] received DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI c236f2de
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch charon: 01[IKE] closing CHILD_SA f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402{1} with SPIs c236f2de_i (0 bytes) c2764521_o (0 bytes) and TS 192.168.0.101/32[udp/l2f] === 176.95.171.124/32[udp/l2f]
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch nm-l2tp-service[559]: xl2tpd started with pid 648
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: xl2tpd[648]: Not looking for kernel SAref support.
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: xl2tpd[648]: Using l2tp kernel support.
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: xl2tpd[648]: xl2tpd version xl2tpd-1.3.10 started on treshch PID:648
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: xl2tpd[648]: Written by Mark Spencer, Copyright (C) 1998, Adtran, Inc.
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: xl2tpd[648]: Forked by Scott Balmos and David Stipp, (C) 2001
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: xl2tpd[648]: Inherited by Jeff McAdams, (C) 2002
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: xl2tpd[648]: Forked again by Xelerance (www.xelerance.com) (C) 2006-2016
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: xl2tpd[648]: Listening on IP address 0.0.0.0, port 1701
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: xl2tpd[648]: Connecting to host 176.95.171.124, port 1701
Nov 16 20:30:24 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: <info>  [1605551424.7685] vpn-connection[0x5591db51a4d0,f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402,"Scoperty",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Nov 16 20:30:38 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: xl2tpd[648]: death_handler: Fatal signal 15 received
Nov 16 20:30:38 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: xl2tpd[648]: Connection 0 closed to 176.95.171.124, port 1701 (Server closing)
Nov 16 20:30:38 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: <warn>  [1605551438.7836] vpn-connection[0x5591db51a4d0,f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402,"Scoperty",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Nov 16 20:30:38 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: <warn>  [1605551438.7839] vpn-connection[0x5591db51a4d0,f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402,"Scoperty",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Nov 16 20:30:38 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: <info>  [1605551438.7841] vpn-connection[0x5591db51a4d0,f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402,"Scoperty",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Nov 16 20:30:38 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
Nov 16 20:30:38 treshch charon: 00[DMN] signal of type SIGINT received. Shutting down
Nov 16 20:30:38 treshch charon: 00[IKE] deleting IKE_SA f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402[1] between 192.168.0.101[192.168.0.101]...176.95.171.124[192.168.178.21]
Nov 16 20:30:38 treshch charon: 00[IKE] sending DELETE for IKE_SA f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402[1]
Nov 16 20:30:38 treshch charon: 00[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 14645769 [ HASH D ]
Nov 16 20:30:38 treshch charon: 00[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.0.101[4500] to 176.95.171.124[4500] (92 bytes)
Nov 16 20:30:38 treshch nm-l2tp-service[559]: ipsec shut down
Nov 16 20:30:38 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: <info>  [1605551438.9029] vpn-connection[0x5591db51a4d0,f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402,"Scoperty",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Nov 16 20:30:38 treshch NetworkManager[26491]: <info>  [1605551438.9087] vpn-connection[0x5591db51a4d0,f3f09d9c-3bd9-4f33-ba98-3808fe632402,"Scoperty",0]: VPN service disappeared
```

Could anyone help to solve this issue and find out what might be wrong with the connection establishment?

Comment: The issue is `charon: 01[IKE] received DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI c236f2de`. So for some reason the remote side is sending a DELETE request after a successful quick mode (i.e. phase 2) connection, probably best to look at the VPN server logs as to why it is sending the DELETE request.